# Michael Spivak's Calculus - Chapter 1 Problem 7 : is there an alternative (neater) proof?

Tags: real-analysis

The question is to prove the well-known fact, that the geometric mean is always less than or equal to the arithmetic mean of two numbers.

**Problem.** Prove that if $0<a<b$, then

### $a<\sqrt{ab}<{\frac{a+b}{2}}<b$

**Proof**. I used the following logic to prove the above inequality.
Since $0<a<b$,

${(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2}>{0}$

${a-2{\sqrt{ab}}+b}>{0}$

$\sqrt{ab}\le{\frac{a+b}{2}}$

Also,

$0<a<b$

$0<{a^2}<ab$

$0<a<{\sqrt{ab}}$

Combining the two results above, we have $a<\sqrt{ab}<{\frac{a+b}{2}}<b$.

My question is, "Is there a neater proof available to validate the above mathematical inequality?"

Comment: I'd say your proof is spot on.

Comment: Why don't you take the time here to show that ${\frac{a+b}{2}} < b$?  It is trivial enough to do, but I don't see how your construction proves that.  Am I missing something obvious?  Also, shouldn't the $\le$ symbol in your first proof component be $<$?

Comment: @par, you are right. The $\le$ symbol should be $<$. And yeah, $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$ is the mid-point, I felt it was trivial enough. Thanks for bringing it up though! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $\sqrt{ab}<{\frac{a+b}{2}}$, I prefer this proof:

$0<(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2=a^2+2ab+b^2-4ab=(a+b)^2-4ab$.

Thus $4ab < (a+b)^2$. Now take square roots.

But my favorite one is the geometric proof (or illustration):

[image]

(picture borrowed from [this page](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/~scott/MeansMeaningMusic_exTempore1981.html)).

Comment: Thank you! Need to get my hands dirty at Algebra again. Though its so much fun!