# Proving Proving $ \sqrt{a \cdot b} \le (a+b)/2$ with a and b in N*

Tags: surreal-numbers

We have variables $a$ and $b$ as natural numbers..

I tried using the reccurence but I got stuck proving:

$\sqrt{(a+1) \cdot (b+1)} \le (a+1+b+1)/2$

May someone help me with this?

Comment: Pls edit the question is not clear

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1327032/589

Comment: @lhf Thank you so much <3

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ equal, unequal, or are we not given that information?

Comment: This is just AM-GM: the arithmetic-geometric inequality. Your proof is under "Proof for (1)" in [Proving AM-GM with induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376862/proving-am-gm-with-induction).

Comment: Surreal numbers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$ (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2 \ge 0$ and $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2=a-2 \sqrt{ab}+b.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: yes definitely!
I just got to add $ 2*\sqrt{ab} $ in both sides